# How do you arrange 3D points in a clockwise order in C?

Tags: c

I have a load of 3D points (points on the cross section of a 3D shape) but they are in a random order... how would I go about putting them in the correct order so that when they are joined together they form the cross section of the 3D shape?

Comment: It sounds like you are dealing with a 2D data set instead of a 3D set. This should simplify your answer greatly. I believe you will need to calculate the mean distance between points to find what points are closest and should be "next" to one another. This is a case where optimization is critical. A good breadth of general sorting algorithms can be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZuD6iUe3Pc. I would research and see what works best for your application.

Comment: If the points are on a cross section of a 3D shape they are coplanar and that is effectively the "2D convex hull" problem (or concave). I disagree that sorting them by distance is a valid solution; the nearest point to some other point may be on the opposite side of the new polygon, not the next point in sequence (as in the case of a quadrilateral diamond shape).

Comment: Let's say you have 3 points forming a triangle. Whether they are clockwise or counterclockwise depends on from which side you look at them.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is "You can't".

Why depends on what "points on the cross section" actually means. There's at least 3 potential interpretations:

a) "points on the cross section" are just random points floating in the middle of the shape of the cross section. In this case a circle (and any other shape) that is large enough will encompass all of the points.

b) "points on the cross section" are random points on the perimeter of the shape of the cross section (e.g. 12 points that could describe a square but none of the points are corners so it could also be an octagon or something else). In this case you still can't determine what the shape is.

c) "points on the cross section" describe the corners of the shape of the cross section. In this case consider points like this:

```
*     *

  *
*     *
```

It could be:

```
*-----*
 \    |
 ,*   |
*-----*
```

..or:

```
*-----*
|   / 
| * __
*-----*
```

..or something else (there's at least 4 possible shapes - more if a "twist" is allowed).

In any case; if you can't determine the shape, then you can't determine the correct order of the points.

If you increase the number of points, then it doesn't really help at all. For example, with 12345 million points that all look like they could describe a rough circle (with minor bumps and dips on the perimeter), then you can't know that it's not supposed to be missing a tiny little sliver straight through its center.

Mostly; I think you need to figure out how the "points on the cross section" were created  and see if you can modify that to give you more information about the points. For example, if (as I suspect) you're starting with a 3D mesh (vertices and polygons in 3D space) and slicing a cross section into it with a cutting plane; then you could track "sliced polygon number" and associate that with the corresponding pair of points.